# Ubuntu 20.04 GDM increments pam_tally without password input

Tags: login, password, gdm, pam

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine with slightly modified common-auth and common-password files to lock the user out for 10 minutes if an incorrect password is tried 10 times. This works fine in the Terminal and elsewhere, but I noticed that in GDM while clicking a user account from the list, not entering anything at all nor pressing enter to actually attempt the login, the tally is incremented. Each time you click a user this "attempt" is also logged to `/var/log/auth.log` by `gdm-password:auth`.

I'm unsure whether this is normal behavior for GDM but if it is I'm curious how to get around it as it's very inconvenient to get locked out for not even making an attempt.

FWIW (not sure if this is causing the issue), here is my PAM setup:
`common-auth`:

```
auth    required                pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=10 unlock_time=600
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

`common-password`:

```
password    requisite            pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=16 reject_username
password    [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure remember=8 use_authtok sha512
password    requisite            pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Any insight into this issue is appreciated.

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that it is possible to login without entering a password or that the user may actually have no password, so `gdm` may first try to login directly, and if it fails then it asks for the password (or whichever verification method is enabled, such as a 2FA code). Not sure, will investigate if I find time today.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was imagining something similar to this could be what's ultimately causing it, but it's something that I would assume gdm has taken in to account and checks first.